# Subprocess check_output of 'systemctl status hostapd' always returning exit code 3

Tags: subprocess, pi, systemctl, hostapd

I am on a raspberry 4B with headless raspbian v10 (buster). I am trying to get the response from the `sudo systemctl status hostapd` command using `subprocess.check_output`.
Simply running `sudo systemctl status hostapd` in the raspi terminal works just fine and I get what I want to see:

```
  sudo systemctl status hostapd
● hostapd.service - Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

However, when I run the code:
`response = subprocess.check_output(['sudo systemctl status hostapd'], shell=True).decode('utf-8')`
I get the error message:
`Error: Command 'systemctl status hostapd.service' returned non-zero exit status 3.`

Adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to the argument list does not provide more information.

Can someone tell me why the error is raised and what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct use of check_output is as follows:

```
subprocess.check_output(['systemctl','status','hostapd']).decode('utf-8')
```

Each argument in the command is part of an array and not the whole command.

Also, I suggest removing "sudo" from the command, and just run your python script with **sudo**.

Comment: `shell=True` is wrong here. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: What is the difference between using sudo within the command compared to calling the parent-python script with sudo?

Comment: When running sudo from within a script that runs under normal user - it will not have the permissions to do so. when using sudo to run the script the shell will ask for a password and then will run it with root permissions